# Image of the adjoint linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $T\colon V\to W$ is a linear map and that $V$ is finite dimensional. Prove that $${\rm Im}(T^\prime) = ({\rm ker}(T))^\circ.$$

I'm struggling to get my head around what each side of my equation represents and I just can't see how to prove this. I know I should show that each side is a subset of the other but I'm finding this tricky to construct. This is revision for a test I have coming up so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Second time you ask this, second time you're asked to answer: what is $\; T'\;$ , anyway?!

Comment: i haven't asked this before... T' is the linear map from W' to V', the dual vector spaces

Comment: The dual spaces are usually denoted by $\;V^*\,,\,W^*\;$, and it isn't clear how you define $\;T': W^*\to V^*\;$ ...

Comment: in my definition, the dual map sends f to f composed with T

Comment: Ok, so $\;(T'(f))(v):=f(Tv)\;$...fine.

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

$$g\in V^*\in\text{Im}\,(T')\implies \exists\;f\in W^*\;\;s.t.\;\;T'(f)=g$$

Now take *any* $\;v\in\ker T\iff Tv=0\;$ , so

$$gv=(T'(f))(v):=f(Tv)=f(0)=0\implies g\in (\ker T)^0$$

Now you try to prove the opposite inclusion.

Comment: thanks - so for the opposite direction:   suppose $g∈(kerT)^0$  so that $g(v)=0$ for v in ker(T). I know that if g is in $Im(T')$ then there is some $f$ such that $f(T(v))=g$ but i really can't see how to get this fact out in this direction

Comment: I am currently struggling with this same question, any further detail on this would be very much appreciated.